# Оставить в строке символы между тире

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Привествую, столкнулся с проблемой. Есть строка
`id = 'table-1-s3'`
Как можно оставить текст только между тире? 
То есть на выходе должно быть `id = '1'`

Answer (score 3):

Можно воспользоваться методом [split](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-methods)

```js
id = 'table-1-s3'
id = id.split('-')[1]
console.log(id)
```

Либо регулярным выражением -

```js
id = 'table-1-s3'
id = id.match(/-(\d+)-/)[1]
console.log(id)
```

Comment: а `.*` зачем в регулярке?

Comment: @Grundy совершенно бесполезен)

Comment: Давайте не будем учить плохому: глобальные переменные без объявлений, переиспользование переменных под разные типы...